# Tor + Irssi (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: tor, irssi

I am trying to get Tor working with Irssi.

The directions at the bottom of this page [Freenode Install Link](http://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml#tor)
say to

```
:~/.irssi$ tor MapAddress 10.40.40.40 p4fsi4ockecnea7l.onion
Feb 12 04:26:51.101 [notice] Tor v0.2.1.29 (r318f470bc5f2ad43). This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Linux x86_64)
Feb 12 04:26:51.101 [warn] Command-line option 'p4fsi4ockecnea7l.onion' with no value. Failing.
Feb 12 04:26:51.101 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Or add it to the torrc file and reload irssi

```
.irssi$ cat /etc/tor/torrc  |grep 10.40.40
mapaddress  10.40.40.40  p4fsi4ockecnea7l.onion
```

This is a paste from within irssi after running `$torify irssi`

```
[04:33] Math::BigInt: couldn't load specified math lib(s), fallback to Math::BigInt::FastCalc at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Crypt/DH.pm line 6
[04:33] 
[04:33] *** Irssi: Loaded script cap_sasl
```

So I thought it was a CPAN module issue.

```
cpan[1]> install Math::BigInt
```

This was also done for FastCalc and retried with force install.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put that mapaddress line to torrc file, not to tor command line.

After that, you must restart tor by running

```
tor
```

or init script

```
/etc/init.d/tor restart
```

After that "torify irssi" should work. BigInt warning shouldn't be problem, as it is falling back to Math::BigInt::FastCalc.

Comment: ...which, despite its name, is damn slow. Install Math::BigInt::GMP. (Although technically it is not necessary to use SASL DH-BLOWFISH when connecting over Tor or SSL; SASL PLAIN is enough. Still I couldn't stand seeing the warning every time.)